# How do I mix JVM based languages in a single Netbeans project?

Tags: java, netbeans, scala, clojure

For example, is it possible to have Scala, Java, and Clojure source all compile/build together properly inside the same project?  Or, do I have to do them as separate project libraries then used by whatever I pick as the "master" project?

If neither of those, how's everyone else doing it?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Unfortunately, while the Java *community* seems to be very enthusiastic about polyglot programming, the IDE vendors haven't really kept up. They generally *do* have plugins for Java, Scala, Clojure, Groovy, Ruby, ECMAScript, Python, C++ projects, but *mixing* multiple languages in *one* project is generally not supported.

In Ruby, for example, it is quite common to use Swing as a GUI via JRuby. But if you want to use Matisse, the NetBeans Swing GUI builder you must use a Java project, you cannot use Matisse in a Ruby project. However, if you use a Java project, then you can't have a Ruby main executable, you must have a Java main executable. Also, you don't get Rake support and other things that the Ruby project type supports. (The ugly workaround is to write a Java main executable which creates a `JRubyEngine` instance by hand, loads the *Ruby* main executable into it and runs it.)

The Eclipse Scala plugin supports a limited amount of polyglotism, but the hoops that they have to jump through are tremendous. Basically, they use runtime bytecode patching to inject Scala Aspects into the Java Development Tools Eclipse plugin, to get type-driven cross-language refactorings to work. The Groovy plugin does similar things, as does AspectJ (in fact, they originally came up with the idea of using aspect weaving to inject new functionality into JDT). So, all of these plugins allow polyglot programming with themselves and Java. But unfortunately not with each other. (Although several of the maintainers have expressed interest in more closely collaborating.)

In general, I fear that the only solution is new IDEs.

Comment: Anyone know where IntelliJ stands on this?

Comment: Yes! Please see my answer to the question.

Answer (score 3):

Rather late to answer this question, but the answer is that IntelliJ IDEA does a very fine job on polyglot programming. I recently watched a demo where one of their developers did a mixed-language application in 5 (!) languages.

They manage to do multi-language-aware syntax coloring, refactoring and more. They've obviously sunk some effort into this and are justifiably proud.

I was very happy to note that IDEA is now (partly) open-sourced.

Comment: Indeed. The way this works is that IDEA doesn't use the language's own tools for syntactic and semantic analysis. Instead IDEA contains a powerful and sophisticated compiler framework (a modern IDE is basically built around an almost complete compiler which is only missing the code generation stage, everything else, parsing, type checking, type inference etc. is there), and they re-implement every language for their IDE. The cool thing is that this compiler framework is very generic, and uses a single shared semantic tree as its backend. So, all code gets compiled into this single shared …

Comment: … semantic tree, and all operations, such as finding references, refactorings, code completion etc. are performed against this single shared semantic tree. That way, it is, for example, possible to perform a *Rename Refactoring* across multiple languages.